# Wrong view DialogFragment on physical device

Tags: android, dialog

I have a problem with the view of a dialog fragment looks good the emulator but it looks bad on a physical device and I do not understand what it should be.

**DialogFragment Error**

[image: DialogFragment Error]

**DialogFragment Expected**

[image: DialogFragment Expected]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_app"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="dialog_test_Fragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_close" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As per your images, you need that black area above the blue layout ? or cross button is getting mixed with the boundries ?

Comment: I need the background color of the dialog to be uniform, and that there is no black area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That must be a title of `DialogFragment`
Try to remove that,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
}
```